# Initialize a variable in c++

Tags: c++

So I want to initialize a variable with a value like this:

```
ADM_job_t job{42};
```

The structure of ADM_job_t is this one:

```
typedef struct adm_job* ADM_job_t;
```

And adm_job looks like this:

```
struct adm_job {
    uint64_t id;
};
```

So my idea was to intialize my variable with an int, because is the "final" type, but I'm getting an error saying that I can not initialize an adm_job with an int. I can not change the structure that has been provided. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Pointers gonna point. You have to give it something to point to, 42 is unlikely to be the address of a valid `adm_job`,  or lose the `*` and make it not a pointer.

Comment: `ADM_job_t` is a _pointer_ to a not yet existing `adm_job`. You are trying to initialise the contents of something which doesn't exist?

Comment: (Also that typedef struct nonsense which hides away pointer types is mainly a `c` idiom, rarely used in `c++`)

Comment: Do not use a C textbook to learn C++, this always ends in tears.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments you do actually have to create a `adm_job` object.

Here is one way

```
adm_job obj{42};
ADM_job_t job = &obj;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the answer:) I tried this and Im getting the following error: 'error: variable ‘adm_job id’ has initializer but incomplete type'. Apparently is in obj of the first line.

Comment: @Georgia This must be because you are not including the header with `struct adm_job { uint64_t id; };` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't change the `adm_job` structure, you can probably still ignore `ADM_job_t` for object creation, and use smart pointers instead.  I recommend starting with something like this:

```
#include <memory>

struct adm_job {
    uint64_t id;
};

typedef struct adm_job* ADM_job_t;

void foo(ADM_job_t p) {
   
}

int main () {
    //auto job = std::make_unique<adm_job>(42);             // C++20
    auto job = std::unique_ptr<adm_job>{new adm_job{42}}; // C++11
    foo(job.get());
}
```

`job`'s type is `std::unique_ptr<adm_job>`.  As you can see, you can still pass the result of `job.get()` to any old C function that makes *non-owning* use of `ADM_job_t`.

You needn't worry about deleting the object like this.

Read about [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). There are some other types of smart pointer depending on who else is going to "own" the pointed two object during its lifetime.